# ¿Como puedo instalar el HAXM?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

He probado todo pero no me deja instalarlo en el eclipse. Os ha pasado esto?

[image: Dejo una captura]

Comment: Has mirado que cumplas los requisitos mínimos para la instalación de HAXM?

Comment: Si he mirado los requisitos y los cumple todos

Comment: Me llama la atención que marca no es compatible con windows, ¿Que versión de Android Studio y Windows usas? @Juan

Comment: De Android Studio la 3.1.4 y de Windows la 10

Comment: ¿Windows 10 de 64bits? es compatible con esta versión. @Juan